Cannot find Authorized Redirected URIs in OAuth 2.0 Client IDs, Google Developer Console
I am using Google Drive API on my spring boot project.
I have set up an app on Google Developer console.
I set my app to be external, and I have set it to be a desktop app on Credentials.
I have created an OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. When I download it in JSON format, it contains the redirect_uri to be "localhost"
although I did not set it to be.
The redirection works fine on my local environment, but it does not work on a production env using an actual https URL.
Someone please help me find the way to set an actual https domain to be the redirect_uri.
I am dying.
I tried changing the redirect_uri on the json file but it doesn't work.
On my java logic, I could set the redirect URI, but still didn't work.
Initiating OAuth 2.0 flow
Handling the redirection
I searched for how to set the authorized redirect uris but it says everywhere that it must be set at OAuth 2.0 Client Ids.
I searched everywhere, but I couldn't find it.
Credentials Screen
OAuthConsent Screen
Also, on OAuth consent screen, i could only find authorized domain.

As you chose a Desktop app, the redirect-uri is meant to be a localhost one. You must choose a server-side web app in order to be able to have other redirect-uris. A Desktop app runs on a local machine, so it is expected to open a browser locally with a local redirect URI. See documentation:

This authorization flow is similar to the one used for web server applications. The main difference is that installed apps must open the system browser and supply a local redirect URI to handle responses from Google's authorization server.

